# Function Alignment in C

Tags: c, memory

What is the default function alignment for C? I know C has 4 bytes aligment for variables... is it the same for functions or are functions 16 bytes aligned? I cant find any information on that.

Comment: This depends on the implementation and platform. 4-byte alignment isn't true in general (though it might be common now for ints).

Comment: Since C11 you can test it yourself with [_AlignOf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Alignof)

Comment: "C has 4 bytes aligment for variables" is not true. Variable allignment depends on its type. Suppose `sizeof( int ) == 4` then allignment of `int` will be 4 (i.e. its address will be divisible by 4 ), but because `sizeof( char ) == 1` always, then allignment of `char` type variable will be 1 (i.e. it can lie on any address).

Comment: @cerveka2 I don't think C requires a 4-byte integer be be aligned on a 4-byte boundary.  That depends on the machine architecture and the compiler implementation.

Comment: @David Note that, in the cppreference page you linked, there is this: *The type-name cannot be function type...*

Comment: Do you want to build a compiler/linker or do you want to copy code into RAM at runtime? Or what problem do you want to solve where you would need alignment requirements of function addresses?

Comment: For example, on x86_64 systems the number of bytes per instruction differs a lot and can be as low as 1 byte. Therefore, technically there is no higher alignment than 1 necessary. Though the linker might impose some, for example for better performance due to cache line usage. -- On 8 bit systems, there is generally no alignment necessary at all, even for wider types. -- Why do you want to know?

Comment: C does not specify it. It only specifies certain details regarding alignment of objects.

Comment: @Gerhardh It can be required in certain conditions for a CPU with code alignment requirements, such as when implementing a CRT or when loading code into RAM as part of some bootloader. I've encountered it when I was coding CRTs and bootloaders for PowerPC microcontrollers, as one example.

Comment: @DavidRanieri No I don't think C allows using `_Alignof` on functions.

Comment: @DavidRanieri: The C standard does not even define applying `_Alignof` to objects, let alone functions. It is defined only for operands that are types, and they must be complete object types.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard does not impose any requirements on the alignment of functions.

C implementations typically align functions as required by the target processor’s requirement for instruction alignment. In Intel’s IA-32 architecture, instructions have diverse lengths and may start at any address, so functions might not have any alignment requirement (other than byte boundaries). In many architectures, instructions are 32 bits and must start at four-byte boundaries, so C implementations start functions at four-byte boundaries.

An implementation could align the entry point of a function more strictly than the hardware requires because it benefits performance.